# Fetch a few columns from GAE Datasotre entity using Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I do have an entity like below and which does have an EmbedMap [The entity details are below]

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Data
{
    @Id long id;
    @EmbedMap private Map<String, SubData> subData = Maps.newHashMap();
}

@Data
public class SubData
{
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
}
```

lets say the datastore entity has below data stored:

**Column                : Data**

id                  : 1

subData.KEY1.data1  : data1

subData.KEY1.data2  : data2

subData.KEY2.data3  : data3

subData.KEY2.data4  : data4

so, I would like to fetch only Data with first 3 coulmns data. Meaning the id and the subData map with only KEY1 data using Objectify?

is there a possibility?

Apologies - Could not format the data in the proper table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either retrieve the entire entity, or only the required properties using a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries). It will not work in your case, though, as you store all data in a single property.

Instead of storing a Map in one property, you can store each value in its own property, using its key as a property kind. Then you can create a projection query that fetches only the properties that you need. I am pretty certain that you can restructure your data model this way.